# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'balance' [MT5]

Tags: python, algorithm, visual-studio-code, metatrader5, expert-advisor

I am using python to write some trading code, however, I have received error as above. I know it connected to MT5 since I also tried different account I had for connection and it works, however, I am unable to retrieve any account information.

Anyone experience enough to help? Would I be missing some installation? I am building this from VSCode if you are asking.

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
from datetime import datetime

if not mt5.initialize(): 
  print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error()) 
  quit() 

D_login = xxx
D_pw = xxx
D_Server = xxx 

mt5.login(D_login, D_pw, D_Server)

acc_info = mt5.account_info
print(acc_info)

bal = acc_info.balance
equity = acc_info.equity

print('Balance :', bal)
print('Equity  :', equity)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `mt5.account_info` to `mt5.account_info()`. You need to call the function.